# Cassandra JVM Constraint

Tags: cassandra

I was building a simple application to query the cassandra database using python cassandra-driver. My requirement is to get 5k queries per second.

```
Spec goes as below:
1. Cassandra 3.11 has one keyspace and one table with 10k records
2. Using Python cassandra-driver to query the data from above table.
3. Deployed cassandra on kubernetes using statefulset on 3 nodes. I am using standard settings with 6 core vCPUs in GKE.
```

I triggered 10k requests for 2-3 minutes. I could get the response from table within 10ms for 80% of the requests but sometimes it goes above 50ms to 100ms for other 20%. When i investigated found that it could be due to JVM issue (2019-03-09T15:30:11.110-0530: 908.491: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0203039 seconds).

logs for reference:

```
2019-03-09 15:30:11.076271     DB time taken !   0:00:00.011658
2019-03-09 15:30:11.080144     DB time taken !   0:00:00.013943
2019-03-09 15:30:11.080273     DB time taken !   0:00:00.013248
2019-03-09 15:30:11.148072     DB time taken !   0:00:00.079689
2019-03-09 15:30:11.148147     DB time taken !   0:00:00.079215
2019-03-09 15:30:11.148367     DB time taken !   0:00:00.067695
2019-03-09 15:30:11.148464     DB time taken !   0:00:00.066383
2019-03-09 15:30:11.154260     DB time taken !   0:00:00.069872
```

code snippet:

```
t1 = datetime.now()
result = session.execute('SELECT * FROM a.b WHERE key = %s', [key])
t2 = datetime.now()

logger.debug('DB time ! ' + '  ' + str(t2 - t1))
```

Here, I want 95% of the requests to be within 50ms but due to JVM 20-30% of them go above 50ms.

When I did a load testing with stress tool there was a satisfactory results but not when i triggered requests through above code:

```
Results:
Op rate                   :   33,700 op/s  [single_read: 33,700 op/s]
Partition rate            :    5,301 pk/s  [single_read: 5,301 pk/s]
Row rate                  :    5,301 row/s [single_read: 5,301 row/s]
Latency mean              :   11.6 ms [single_read: 11.6 ms]
Latency median            :    6.2 ms [single_read: 6.2 ms]
Latency 95th percentile   :   41.5 ms [single_read: 41.5 ms]
Latency 99th percentile   :   61.8 ms [single_read: 61.8 ms]
Latency 99.9th percentile :  100.9 ms [single_read: 100.9 ms]
Latency max               :  263.7 ms [single_read: 263.7 ms]
Total partitions          :    318,523 [single_read: 318,523]
Total errors              :          0 [single_read: 0]
Total GC count            : 0
Total GC memory           : 0.000 KiB
Total GC time             :    0.0 seconds
Avg GC time               :    NaN ms
StdDev GC time            :    0.0 ms
Total operation time      : 00:01:00
```

I have gone through so many suggestions but nowhere found solution with this requirement.

Can someone guide me how to reduce the time taken while JVM runs inside the cassandra or shrink the time that cassandra takes to run JVM?

Note:
I did all possible tuning guidelines (row-cache, bloom filter, compaction etc) to get the above performance.

```
cqlsh:a> select * from b where key = '34823049392304' ;

 key            | name | password
----------------+------+-----------
 34823049392304 | test | test33k23

(1 rows)

Tracing session: 467f0a90-4489-11e9-88ab-3ff1c33f5d2f

 activity                                                                             | timestamp                  | source     | source_elapsed | client
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+------------+----------------+-----------
                                                                   Execute CQL3 query | 2019-03-12 05:39:59.545000 | 10.12.88.4 |              0 | 127.0.0.1
 Parsing select * from b where key = '34823049392304' ; [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2019-03-12 05:39:59.545000 | 10.12.88.4 |            328 | 127.0.0.1
                                    Preparing statement [Native-Transport-Requests-1] | 2019-03-12 05:39:59.546000 | 10.12.88.4 |            565 | 127.0.0.1
                                                          Row cache hit [ReadStage-3] | 2019-03-12 05:39:59.547000 | 10.12.88.4 |           1467 | 127.0.0.1
                                 Read 1 live rows and 0 tombstone cells [ReadStage-3] | 2019-03-12 05:39:59.547000 | 10.12.88.4 |           1729 | 127.0.0.1
                                                                     Request complete | 2019-03-12 05:39:59.547018 | 10.12.88.4 |           2018 | 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Can you tell a little more about your cluster? How many nodes? How much heap is usesd? Did you tune any of the JVM parameters?

Comment: @Mandraenke: I am using 3 node statefulset cluster with 8CPUs/24GM memory. Internally in the Yaml file defining cpu: "6000m" and memory: 3Gi for each. I have set heap sizes (- name: MAX_HEAP_SIZE value: 2400M and - name: HEAP_NEWSIZE value: 600M) as env variables in yaml file.           
Heap Memory (MB)       : 449.63 / 2340.00. Only above two are updated and nothing else.

Comment: @Mandraenke: I used the https://github.com/docker-library/cassandra 3.11 docker file to build the image and updated the row key cache fields to hold 10k rows/25MB of data. Used https://github.com/IBM/Scalable-Cassandra-deployment-on-Kubernetes/blob/master/cassandra-statefulset.yaml yaml file to deploy it into kubernetes cluster. Let me know if you need much more information.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your using ZGC (jdk11 requires C* 4.0) your gonna get GCs in the low 100ms or more which will show up that way in for requests by default. Cassandra mitigates internally this between each other with speculative retry but that does not help when the coordinator GCs. To not have that impact your client you need to speculate from client side, see: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.2/manual/speculative_execution/ This way if the coordinator hits a GC you will hit a 2nd node. For sub 10ms though you need to set speculation to 0ms since network latency tends to ruin things otherwise.

Note that the python driver is by far the worst performing of the drivers so if you are really pushing for low latency high throughput requests id recommend using the java, c++ or even nodejs driver before the python one. This alone might be the difference you see between cassandra-stress (java driver) and your python app.

Comment: I am still working on java. Will let you know once i have an update.                              
I tried using Golang. In Golang i tried go-routine concept like trigger a requests to 3 routines which are connecting to 3 nodes. Such that if any routine which is in touch with JVM node i can get the response bit faster from other node. Here, i found one trouble that we are not sure which of the 3 routine triggered first. This is an issue that which routine is triggered first will not know. So, if the routine which hit the JVM node comes fast than other two routine then there is no use here.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Chris suggestion i tried Go lang cassandra driver and I could achieve the response time as I required i.e. 90% of the requests were served within a millisecond. I agree that cassandra DB nodes will be burdened. The complete code is in the link [cassandra performance with Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382591/is-this-proper-go-code-which-is-connecting-to-cassandra-db)

Performance stats:

```
 Running 1m test @ http://10.12.206.8:8081/
  2 threads and 2 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency     1.53ms  654.92us  30.59ms   96.60%
    Req/Sec   667.35     58.83   818.00     68.67%
  79763 requests in 1.00m, 14.91MB read
Requests/sec:   1328.29
Transfer/sec:    254.24KB
```

sample logs (if you go through the code you can co-relate the log details):

```
    Seed 0  2019-03-23 09:25:42.416604785 +0000 UTC m=+1528.998487360   2019-03-23 09:25:42.41787099 +0000 UTC m=+1528.999753571   1.266211ms
  1.2236ms  In First Attempt
  1.244515ms
 Seed 0  2019-03-23 09:25:42.418236332 +0000 UTC m=+1529.000118895   2019-03-23 09:25:42.419480829 +0000 UTC m=+1529.001363410   1.244515ms
  949.845µs  In First Attempt
  969.877µs
 Seed 0  2019-03-23 09:25:42.419879164 +0000 UTC m=+1529.001761725   2019-03-23 09:25:42.420849019 +0000 UTC m=+1529.002731602   969.877µs
  1.30004ms  In First Attempt
  1.320535ms
 Seed 0  2019-03-23 09:25:42.421222097 +0000 UTC m=+1529.003104671   2019-03-23 09:25:42.422542624 +0000 UTC m=+1529.004425206   1.320535ms
  1.181071ms  In First Attempt
  1.199418ms
 Seed 0  2019-03-23 09:25:42.422874452 +0000 UTC m=+1529.004757012   2019-03-23 09:25:42.424073845 +0000 UTC m=+1529.005956430   1.199418ms
```

I had a doubt in my code so requested some proficient team to have a look so raised a question but that code can be utilized by someone.